# How to access an Office IEnumerable interface?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, powerpoint, office-interop

I am trying to write a C# add-in for PowerPoint with VS2013. But (after some years of absence in programming :) I am struggling with C#.

Task is to let the user choose one installed proofing language and set it for all slides.

First, it seems that PowerPoint doesn't have a function for fetching the installed/available proofing languages, but obviously Word has. So I started with Word and found:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Languages
```

But I have not managed to get a collection of the proofing languages; it's an IEnumerable interface so I can't instantiate it.

What is the correct code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Languages property to get the collection of languages.

[_Application.Languages Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.languages(v=office.14).aspx)

> Returns a Languages collection that represents the proofing languages
>   listed in the Language dialog box.

Here [_Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application_members(v=office.14).aspx) represents the Microsoft Office Word application.